# Hold more than one value in Session?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

The project at Login checks the users details and the service area they belong too. It was just one area but now they can belong to more than one.

The code is how it was set up to work using `Session`.

```
var user = (from u in db.tbl_UserServiceAreaDetails
            where u.tbl_User.UserName.Equals(txt_LoginName.Text)
            && u.tbl_User.Password.Equals(txt_Password.Text)
            select u).FirstOrDefault();

if (user != null)
{
Session["Username"] = user.tbl_User.UserName;

Session["ServiceArea"] = user.tbl_ServiceArea.ServiceArea;

Session["ServiceAreaID"] = user.serviceAreaID;
```

The `ServiceArea` can now be many. Could I try a `foreach` over the `serviceAreaID` which is in a link table between `User` and `Servicearea` called `serviceAreaDetails` and the `serviceAreaID` is mapped to the `serviceAreaId` in `tbl_ServiceArea` and `UserAreaID` mapped to `userId` in `tbl_User`.

Would `foreach (ListItem item in user.ServiceAreaID)` be able to work?

If i get the `userId` when the user logs in and pass that into my `Foreach` could I some how set that to the `Session`. As the Index page displays the `servicearea` the user belongs too which can now be more than one.

Comment: How about simply storing an array / list instead of just a single value... note you may want to change the key (`"ServiceAreaID"`) to avoid issues when migrating on a live production system.

Comment: Not related to your question per se, but it looks like you're storing passwords in plain text in your database. You probably do not want to do that.

Comment: @MarcGravell How would I do that?

Comment: @StudentRik you don't make it clear at what point you'll have multiple ids, so that is a little hard to advise on. In your example there is only 1.

Comment: @MarcGravell The User can now belong to multiple `serviceareas` and Im unsure as to how to check for multiple areas.

Comment: @StudentRik let's say that instead of a single value, `user.ServiceAreas` was a list of the multiple values; you just store them, fetch them out when needed, and check how many/which are there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store also complex objects in the session, so create a class for your users, where all the areas with ids are stored to the user and save this class in the session

```
class UserClass
{
    public string userName;
    public Dictionary<int, string> serviceArea = new Dictionary<int,string>();
}

UserClass user = new UserClass();

Session["User"] = user;

user = (UserClass)Session["User"];
```

---

Reply to comment:
Yes, feel free to use a Getter&Setter
Yes, thats how a Dictionary works, the first parameter is the key, the second the value, it's also flexible to be used with any objects

```
UserClass user = new UserClass();

user.userName = "Rik";

foreach(...serviceArea...) // Or whatever loop you like
{
    user.serviceArea.Add(serviceAreaID, serviceArea);
}
```

Comment: In the public string userName would I do `{get;set;}` and as for the `Dictionary` I have never used a Dictionary. is the int for the `serviceareaID` and string for `servicearea`. Im still unsure as to how i would work this. i.e:`user.username = user.tbl_user.UserName` ? would that be right?

Comment: I put the reply in the post

Comment: So would all my three `Sessions` be in one User `Session`

Comment: To do that, you can make a List or an Array with the UserClass

Answer (score 0):

What I find is useful is creating a list of Objects and adding that to a session.  You can then cast session variables to that object type and iterate over it.  For example:

```
Public Class someClass
    Public Property userName as String
    Public Property FirstName as String     
End Class
```

You can then Create a list of this type and add it to a session:

```
dim myList as new list(of someClass)
dim newSomeClass as new someClass

newSomeClass.userName="username1"
newSomeClass.FirstName="Jason"
myList.add(newSomeClass)

newSomeClass.userName="username2"
newSomeClass.FirstName="Frank"
myList.add(newSomeClass)

Session.add("mySessionId",myList)
```

You can then cast that session to myList and iterate over it somewhere else:

```
Dim myList as new list(of someClass)
if(Session("mySessionId") isNot nothing) then
    myList = Session("mySessionId")

    for each n as someClass in myList
      'iterate
    next
end if
```

You just need to be careful that you destroy these session when finished and that you aren't consuming to much resources between postbacks.  If you have any questions, let me know.